# Chrome Extension - loading image with src tag error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: javascript, angular, xss, angular2-template

I have this HTML:

```
<mat-card-content>
   <img mat-card-image src="{{userProfilePictureURL}}">
</mat-card-content>
```

userProfilePictureURL is set too:

```
chrome.extension.getURL('dist/assets/images/anonymoose.png')
```

which is:

```
chromeextension://omelijcoklpokoeobkpepoipjpbakoeo/dist/assets/images/anonymoose.png
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

perhaps I need to sanitize the url?